# Build APK - ERROR - app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug

Tags: android, android-studio, dex

I watched so many threads here and still didnt find working solution.

**When I want to BUILD APK, I get this main error:**

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing
>   java process with main class com.android.dx.command.Main with
>   arguments {--dex --num-threads=4 --multi-dex --main-dex-list
>   C:\Users\ratik\Desktop\BUILDBOX\VOLUNTEER\STUDIO\app\build\intermediates\multi-dex\debug\maindexlist.txt
>   --output C:\Users\ratik\Desktop\BUILDBOX\VOLUNTEER\STUDIO\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dex\debug\folders\1000\1f\main
>   C:\Users\ratik\Desktop\BUILDBOX\VOLUNTEER\STUDIO\app\build\intermediates\transforms\jarMerging\debug\jars\1\1f\combined.jar}

There is few more errors, but then apear only sometimes, some of them:

> Error:    at
>   com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
>
> Error:    at
>   com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:723)
>
> Error:    at
>   com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)
>
> Error:java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

**What I tried:**

In build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.biif.volunteer"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 25
        multiDexEnabled true

        ndk {
            moduleName "player_shared"
        }

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }


    }
    sourceSets.main {
        jni.srcDirs = []// <-- disable automatic ndk-build call
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'){exclude module: 'support-v4'}
    compile files('libs/dagger-1.2.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/javax.inject-1.jar')
    compile files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/support-v4-19.0.1.jar')
    compile ('com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1')
}
```

In Manifest

> android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"

Plus I turned off Instant run (saw in one thread here).

**Nothing helped :( Any ideas please? Thanks for help guys :)**

Comment: After implementing:     compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.1'
I get error:Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/text/TextUtilsCompat.class

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I included gradle.properties file in the project with:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx10248m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

and it works.

Comment: This was helpful however, I found a good write up by Reto Meier about Dex in Process [here](https://medium.com/google-developers/faster-android-studio-builds-with-dex-in-process-5988ed8aa37e) . Just in case one needs more information and deep explanation about the same

Comment: @jcmore2 Smart answer. Thanks